# Rails - how to call methods from lib directory?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have this method in the lib dir (file `my_class_name.rb`):

```
class MyClassName
  def doSomething
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

in the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'my_class_name'

  def show_stats
    ::MyClassName.doSomething()
  end
end
```

returns

> undefined method `doSomething' for MyClassName:Class

How to properly call this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written a class with an instance method, so if you want to call it how you've written it you'll need to write:

```
  mcn = MyClassName.new
  mcn.doSomething
```

(by creating an instance, and then calling the method on that instance)

If what you want is a class method, define it as:

```
class MyClassName
  def self.doSomething
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

and call it like: `MyClassName.doSomething`

Answer (score 0):

You have made and instance method not class method, change your code as follow, plus i would suggest you instead of making it as a class make it a module and include in your model and call doSomething from model.

```
class MyClassName
  def self.doSomething
    ...
  end
  ...
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'my_class_name'

  def show_stats
    MyClassName.doSomething()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make it work as is (with tiny change) then you should create an instance of MyClassName e.g. ::MyClassName.*new*.doSomething()

```
class MyClassName
  def doSomething
    ...
  end
  ...
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'my_class_name'

  def show_stats
    ::MyClassName.new.doSomething()
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyClassName
  def self.doSomething
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```