# Rails Import Class Method from lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure out why this will not work.

I have a class in lib with this code:

```
    class SortMethods
  def initialize(direction, sort)
    @mydirection = direction
    @mysort = sort
  end
  def sort_column(table, field)
    table.column_names.include?(@mysort) ? @mysort : field
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(@mydirection) ? @mydirection : "asc"
  end
end
```

In my trucks_controller I have this code:

```
    class TrucksController < ApplicationController
  # GET /trucks
  # GET /trucks.json
  require 'sort_methods'
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  def index
    search = params[:search]
    msm = SortMethods.new(params[:direction], params[:sort])
    @trucks = Truck.search(search).order(msm.sort_column(Truck, "truck_no") + " " + msm.sort_direction)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trucks }
    end
  end
end
```

What I don't understand is what I am doing wrong, I've tried everything that was suggested in this post, another person had the same question yet it does not works.  What am I doing wrong?

post: [Rails - how to call methods from lib directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110453/rails-how-to-call-methods-from-lib-directory)

I should add that i also tried adding .self and it still does not works.

Comment: please show the code for sort_column. Are you trying to access the params hash inside it?

Comment: Aparently you are calling `params` on your `SortMethods` class. And you are not passing it to the `new` or `sort_column` methods.

Comment: @MurifoX I don't quite understand what you said, how would I fix that, could you by any chance post an answer?  I'm new to rails, trying to learn how all this is properly done.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `sort_column` method?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the solution instead of just explaining your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your error.  `undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<SortMethods:0x2224008>`

That means that `SortMethods` is trying to call `params[]`.

Only controllers can have access to the `params` object.

In your SortMethods class, make sure that you are not calling the `params` object. If you need a parameter from the web, pass it in as an argument to one of your methods.  Something like this will work.

```
class SortMethods
  def initialize(param)
    @param = param
  end

  def sort_column(table, field)
    puts @param
  end

  def sort_direction
    #some action
  end
end
```

Then in your controller,

```
def index
  msm = SortMethods.new(params[:something])
  ...
end
```

Conceptually you could pass the entire `params` object, but you wouldn't want that because you should only take what you need.

Comment: `Truck.search` is not the problem, it's either `sort_column` or `sort_direction`

Comment: I tried your method and I got the same error.  I edited my code and gave you the whole thing.  There is also a helper method involved but I don't think you need that, do you?

Comment: The reason why I have this class in a lib is because I am going to be calling it about 20 times, from different controllers.  They all have their own tables such as Truck Company Driver, etc...  So I can't always call Truck.column_names.... It changes with each controller.  I was attempting to pass in that Truck through parameters so that I may use it in the lib

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that it's not importing the class properly. Look at this part of the error:

```
#<SortMethods:0x2224008>
```

This represents an instance of SortMethods, which means that it has been imported and instantiated properly. What the error is telling you is that the SortMethods class has no attribute or method called params, which means that **somewhere inside the code of those 2 methods defined inside SortMethods you're trying to use params**, which is a controllers property that is not accessible anywhere else (except in the view).

Edit: If you need to access something which is in the params hash, you have to modify your methods to take arguments, and then call them passing whatever you need from the params hash as parameters, then use them inside the function as usual.

Comment: I updated my code to show the all methods, from everything you said I believe the problem was in there, however I don't still quite understand how to fix it.

Comment: It's easy, I think the problem is that you're coming from php or some other procedural language. In ruby, and by extension in every Object oriented high level language,not all variables are available everywhere. params[] is a hash defined inside the controller. If you call some other object from the controller, this other object (SortMethods in your case) doesn't have access to anything from the controller, included the params[] hash. Only what you pass as arguments will be. Just like you're passing table and field as arguments to make them available to the sort_colum method, pass params too!

Comment: I come from java and c# as well as asp.net and AJAX.  I have done OOP and MVC with java, i get the general concept, the biggest problem I have with rails is understanding what I can access where, I think if I can get that down that I would do well with ruby and rails.  Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Then I can't see how you didn't understand this. All of the languages you mentioned (AJAX is not a language btw) would throw the same error if you attempted to do what you did here. The params hash is a property of the Controller object. If you call the SortMethod object, you can't access the controller properties, they are not in their scope. What's confusing you exactly?